# U-SQL - Vertex Failure: Invalid character when attempting to convert column data

Tags: sql, casting, analytics, azure-data-lake, u-sql

For all my CSV sources, I set the extractor to:

```
USING Extractors.Csv(silent:true,skipFirstNRows:1);  
- silent is set to true to ignore bad rows
- skipFirstNRows is set to 1 to skip the header row
```

Yet oddly, I still get this error:

```
HEX: "223122" Invalid character when converting input record.
Position: line 2, column index: 7, column name: "IncludeOnCheck".
Invalid character when attempting to convert column data.
```

Data (sample row & row in question)

```
29,1,10,DC Tax,DC Tax,0.100000,0.00,1,1,1,2014-07-12 21:34:52.4200000 +00:00,NULL,NULL,0,-1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,1031,NULL,0,0
33,4,10,Amenities,Amenities,1.000000,0.00,1,0,1,2014-07-12 21:34:54.1330000 +00:00,NULL,NULL,0,-1,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,1031,NULL,0,0
```

Column Definition

```
EXTRACT AncillaryAmountTypeID int,
        AncillaryAmountCategoryID int,
        CustomerID int,
        CheckTitle string,
        ReportTitle string,
        Percentage decimal,
        FixedAmount decimal,
        IncludeOnCheck bool,
        AutoCalculate bool,
        StoreAtCheckLevel bool?,
        DateTimeModified DateTime?,
        CheckTitleToken Guid?,
        ReportTitleToken Guid?,
        DeletedFlag bool,
        MaxUsageQty int?,
        ApplyToBasePriceOnly bool?,
        Exclusive bool,
        IsItem bool,
        MinValue decimal,
        MaxValue decimal,
        ItemGroupID int?,
        LocationID int,
        ApplicationOrder int?,
        RequiresReason bool,
        Exemptable bool?
```

Questions

1. Why am I getting conversion errors when I specified silent is true,
   which should ignore any bad rows, right?
2. The character it tried to convert was "1", and into a boolean. Is U-SQL or ADLA not able to understand or convert 1 and 0 into booleans?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also observed this behavior, it does not convert 0 or 1 into bool automatically. If you want to do that then EXTRACT it as int and then convert it into bool using Convert.ToBoolean method.

I think silent switch only works when there is a mismatch between provided schema and the schema of an actual data.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt764098.aspx) is the documentation for the `silent` parameter: It only ignores conversion errors if your target type is nullable. Otherwise it still errors.

Also, we are following C# semantics on conversion as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621366.aspx).